# Querying results from mysql DB to a list

Tags: python, mysql-python

Eventually I would like to output the hosts to a list.

```
try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='passwd', 
database='some_db')
  cursor = cnx.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

retrieveQuery = ("SELECT host_name,product from server")
cursor.execute(retrieveQuery)
for host,prod in cursor:
print ("{},{}".format(host,prod))
```

Result looks good: [host1,PowerEdge]

```
retrieveQuery = ("SELECT host_name from server")
cursor.execute(retrieveQuery)
for host in cursor:
print ("{}".format(host))
```

Result: (u'host1',)

Why am I seeing (u',) with the same code but when just one column is selected ?
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you wondering why there is a `u` before the string or why there is a comma (or both) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cursor` row result is always `tuple` type, try:

```
for row in cursor:
    print ("{}".format(row.host_name))
```

or

```
for host, in cursor:
    print ("{}".format(host))
```